# How get URL from Chrome processes/tabs with VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to get the URLs from all running Chrome tabs so that I can compare them with a allready known static URL. When the correct tab is found, use that Chrome tab to navigate to a new page (the static URL). How would I go about to get this result in VBScript?

```vb
Dim Processes, Process
Set Processes = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_Process")

For Each Process In Processes
    If InStr(1, process.Name, "chrome", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        WScript.Echo process.Name
    End If
Next
```

With this piece of script I can all chrome processes but I have no clue how to get the URL from each process.

Comment: AFAIK you can't. Chrome doesn't expose an API that could be used from VBScript to get the information you want.